# Error: ESLint couldn't find the config "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked" to extend from

Tags: typescript, eslint, lint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

I've looked around and can't find anything quite matching this, and none of the fixes have solved it for me.  I'm relatively new to eslint, and could really use some help.

My goal is to turn on the rule `"no-floating-promises"` for my TypeScript project.  When I add it and run lint, I get hundreds of instances of:
`error  Definition for rule 'no-floating-promises' was not found  no-floating-promises`. From what I've read, it's beause I need to extend:
`"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked"`

So, I update my `.eslintrc.json` to add `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked"` to extends.

Now, when I run lint, I get:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.45.0

ESLint couldn't find the config "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

The config "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked" was referenced from the config file in "/Users/[username]/gitdir/[project]/.eslintrc.json".

If you still have problems, please stop by https://eslint.org/chat/help to chat with the team.
```

I'm struggling to figure out my next steps in troubleshooting this. Any direction would be appreciated!

My .eslintrc.json includes:

```
{
  "env": {
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest"
  },
"plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
...
"no-floating-promises": "warn"
}
```

I also tried:

```
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "tsconfigRootDir": "__dirname",
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
  },
```

to no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [blog post](https://ozum.net/how-to-fix-eslint-error-definition-for-rule-was-not-found/) about potential solutions of this error and took the relevant part here. You should prefix the name of the rule when the rule comes from a plugin. `@typescript-eslint` in this case.

```json
{
  "rules": {
-   "no-floating-promises": "warn"
+   "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "warn"
  }
}
```

There are two additional problems with the config you wrote. They are probably typos when writing the post because the error you mentioned is not related to them.

1. You forgot `parserOptions.project`. (You fixed that in the second example). `parserOptions.project` is required if you extend from a configuration or use a rule that checks types because they need TypeScript for type checking. You use `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked`. You may use a boolean when the TypeScript configuration file is named with the default `tsconfig.json`.
2. You added `no-floating-promises` to the root. It should be in the `rules`.

Also, consider to use "error" instead of "warn". `eslint` command may not exit with an error code for "warn" (depends on command line parameters).

Below is the final config:

```json
{
  "env": {
    "es2021": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked"
  ],
  "overrides": [],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "project": true
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "warn"
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"` anymore - the type-checked version is a replacement.